# Do I have wifi on the main Peru bus companies, such as Cruz del Sur, Ormeño or Oltursa?

Tags: buses, peru, wifi

Do I have wireless internet on the main Peru bus companies, such as Cruz del Sur, Ormeño or Oltursa ?

That would be nice since my bus trips usually last around 10 hours

Comment: Are you only asking about this companies?, because i can do some research here in Peru if there is another one besides those.

Comment: @Washu No it is not necessary thanks! I think I will only travel with these companies. It is a bit off-topic, but I was wondering if they all charge, more or less, the same price for the travel?

Comment: Cruz del Sur charges more than Ormeño and Oltursa. I'm leaving my job right now as soon as i get home i will call and ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have called the bus companies and checked some testimonies on web and of my friends regarding the WiFi on this buses. I'm glad to tell you that the 3 of them have the service, however it is not available for all the routes.

- Cruz del Sur: It has WiFi available for 80% of the routes. It is not a fast connection but you can check email, and look at webpages; but it would be a bad idea to use it for viewing YouTube videos and such.
- Ormeño: It has WiFi for their international routes.
- Oltursa: It has WiFi for only 50% of destinations.

Of course the WiFi service is only for the premium tickets so you will have to pay extra and speed is not that great. You have to know that 70% of the internet users here in Peru only have 2Mb... so it is going to be slow and possibly get disconnected during some hours in the trip.

Comment: hey! Thanks very much for calling them. Very kind of you

Comment: @Patrick No worries, If you can join the chat and provide me the route i can be more specific and give you the actual cost of it.

Answer (score 7):

Some of the companies tend to advertise wifi connection onboard, but we encountered the first actually working one in Chile.

I would try to go through the desks of different bus companies in the bus station. If they say that they offer wifi in the bus then give them little bit hard time with questions about it and finally go with the one who sounds most believable. After that its just testing but don't expect too much.